# JQuery clockpicker not triggering change event on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In a codebase I'm working on there's this type of callback binding where something has to happen whenever any input gets changed

```
$(document.body).on('change', '.input-sm', function (){
 ...
})
```

The thing is, some input-sms are changed via a clockpicker, which does not trigger the 'change' event. How would I make this work? Ideally, I'd like clockpicker to trigger the change event.

http://jsfiddle.net/4zg3w5sj/7/

EDIT: A callback is being bound to multiple inputs with clockpickers at once, so I can't use the input variable to trigger the change event (except if I explicitly iterate over the inputs I guess)

Comment: You can use afterDone event http://jsfiddle.net/4zg3w5sj/2/

Comment: and if you want to use change event then you can trigger `change()` in `afterDone` http://jsfiddle.net/4zg3w5sj/3/

Comment: right... of course. I can trigger change there!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the clockpicker callbacks

> beforeHourSelect :    callback function triggered before user makes an
>   hour selection
>
> afterHourSelect    :  callback function triggered after user makes an
>   hour selection
>
> beforeDone     :  callback function triggered before time is written to
>   input
>
> afterDone : callback function triggered after time is written to input

```
input.clockpicker({
    autoclose: true,
    afterDone: function() {
       input.trigger("change");       
    }
});
```

I've figure out the issue

The plugin trigger the change event but they use [triggerHandler](http://api.jquery.com/triggerhandler/) instead of [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) that mean you can't add listener on body , you have to listen directly on the input

```
// Hours and minutes are selected
    ClockPicker.prototype.done = function() {
        raiseCallback(this.options.beforeDone);
        this.hide();
        var last = this.input.prop('value'),
            value = leadingZero(this.hours) + ':' + leadingZero(this.minutes);
        if  (this.options.twelvehour) {
            value = value + this.amOrPm;
        }

        this.input.prop('value', value);
        if (value !== last) {
            this.input.triggerHandler('change');
            if (! this.isInput) {
                this.element.trigger('change');
            }
        }

        if (this.options.autoclose) {
            this.input.trigger('blur');
        }

        raiseCallback(this.options.afterDone);
    };
```

see here a fix

```
 var input = $('#input-a');
    var value = input.val();
    // bind multiple inputs
    $('.myinput').clockpicker({
        autoclose: true,
        afterDone: function() {
        console.log("test");
        }
    });

    // in the actual code it's not tied to an id but to a non-unique class
    // does not trigger if changed by clock-picker
    $(".myinput").on('change', function(){
        console.log("!!!!")
    })
```

Comment: unfortunately I don't have direct access to the input, because the event is bound to multiple inputs at once.

Comment: It's 5 years later, but I edited the clockpicker.js file to trigger the change event even if the input is an input tag because.... why the heck would it not already?